# 301 Redirect Directory Matching

Tags: redirect, seo

I have been unable to get an answer on this one. Basically, I have a bunch of urls, that go like this:

- www.mysite.com/gb/best-price/description.shtml
- www.mysite.com/fr/best-price/description.shtml
- www.mysite.com/jp/best-price/description.shtml

I need them to be redirected to their direct match pages, that go like this:

- www.mysite.com/gb/best-price/index.shtml
- www.mysite.com/fr/best-price/index.shtml
- www.mysite.com/jp/best-price/index.shtml

I know I could do a 1-to-1 redirect, but truth is, I have hundreds of such urls.. how do I get the redirect to match to the destination urls, in bulk without doing a 1-to-1? For example, /gb/best-price/description.shtml to /gb/best-price/index.shtml

Basically, gb to gb, fr to fr, jp to jp. The only difference in the original and new urls are the html file names (original ends with description.shtml, new urls end with index.shtml).

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could tried:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/best-price/description.shtml ^//1/best-price/index.shtml permanent;
```

I think it could help you. !!

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it.. :)